# ARM Templates - Referencing a resource property inside the Concat function

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

**Situation**: In my template structure, I have a few nested templates. One of the nested templates is receiving as a parameter the ID of the resource and some other parameters.
Already in the **name** section of the resource, I have to **concat** the following:
**1.** One of the parameter values.
**2.** Resource property via the **reference** function.
So the code would like something like the following:

`{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "dnsZoneName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "privateendpointInterface": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "variables": {
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/privateDnsZones/A",
            "apiVersion": "2018-09-01",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('dnsZoneName'),reference(parameters('privateendpointInterface'),'2019-09-01','Full').properties.ipConfigurations[0].properties.privateLinkConnectionProperties.fqdns[0])]",
            "properties": {
                "aRecords": [
                    {
                        "ipv4Address": "10.1.1.1"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}`

**Issue**: By design, it is not allowed to use reference function inside the concat function, and I can not pre-store the referenced value in the variables section.

Comment: You should be able to use `resourceId` to resolve dependency identities.

Comment: Did you look into outputs? What this gives you is some flexibility to output property of a resource that can then be used in another template. Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-outputs?tabs=azure-powershell

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on the resourceId for solving the dependencies?

Comment: Actually, I am using outputs, this template is receiving the property of the Private Link, which is one of the Interface ID's which I need to dig into.